# How can we use Admin Js file in custom theme in magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I want to modify File `/vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/adminhtml/web/js/components/bundle-user-defined-checkbox.js`.
I have a custom theme.

I have put this file `app/design/adminhtml/Magento/backend/Magento_Bundle/web/js/components/bundle-user-defined-checkbox.js` but doesn't work.

Comment: override with custom module, this approach you gotta extend your theme by backend theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

1. Add **requirejs-config.js** in the below path

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js

then add the below code to it

```
var config = {
map: {
   '*': {
     'Magento_Bundle/js/components/bundle-user-defined-checkbox': 
'Vendor_ModuleName/js/bundle-user-defined-checkbox'
     }
   }
};
```

**Vendor_ModuleName** - is your module name which is in registration.php

then copy the file from below path

> /vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/adminhtml/web/js/components/bundle-user-defined-checkbox.js

and paste it in below path and make your changes there

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/web/js/bundle-user-defined-checkbox.js

then run the below commands to see your changes

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

then see your changes in frontend

Hope this helps .

Comment: Is this working?

Comment: yes it does but this approach is to add custom js via custom module...

Comment: I tried it but it still taking the original 3rd party js file only.

Comment: Can you help me with this? -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305247/how-to-override-3rd-party-module-requirejs-config-js-film-in-my-custom-module