# Magento 2 overriding core js file not working

Tags: magento2.2

I have a core js file that I want to override, but everything I have tried has failed, including essentially copying the method used by another core file being overridden that does work. Here is what I have in my requirejs.config.js so far:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart':'js/view/minicart', //This one is overriden properly
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order':'js/action/place-order' //This one won't override
        }
    }
};
```

Here are the paths to both files that won't override:

core file: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/place-order.js`

override file: `app/design/frontend/MyNamespace/mymodule/Magento_Checkout/web/js/action/place-order.js`

And for reference, here are the paths to the one that IS being overridden:

core file: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js`

override file:

```
app/design/frontend/MyNamespace/mymodule/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/minicart.js
```

I am using Magento 2.2.6 as well.

I have cleared the cache multiple times and because I am in a dev environment, I don't need to deploy static content, but I tried it anyway, still didn't work. I can't figure out why one would override and the other doesn't.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try the below answer and let me know for queries :) @EricBrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're overriding by your theme then you don't need **requirejs-config.js** because it's fallback methodology so just place the file in your theme. The path should be like this

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/minicart.js

Hoping this would be your theme **MyNamespace/mymodule** say it eg : **Smarwave/porto**

There are two ways to override core js

1. One by just moving it the theme
2. Another one by custom module [Refer this to override custom js by
   custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267806/how-can-we-use-admin-js-file-in-custom-theme-in-magento-2/267811#267811)

since I don't know why it's not done for you because it seems you done everything right.

Just remove the **requirejs-config.js** from your theme and move your core js to theme like above.

After moving your files to your theme do run the following commands,

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this helps you to sort out your issue.

Comment: This works, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the only way to apply your change is to delete the static files.
Sometimes not even cache buster tools are working...

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
```

You may need to recompile your code afterwards.