# How to Override 3rd party module requirejs-config.js file in my custom module?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, requirejs, requirejs-config.js, override-model

[image]

The above one is the 3rd party module's require-config.js. It contains the js file inside the adminhtml/web/js. I want to override that.

So I created a custom module and made changes in the require-config.js like below. 
[image]

But it is not overriding the original js file of that 3rd party module. I also put the module as a sequence like below.

```
<module name="Override_Barcode" schema_version="1.0.1" setup_version="1.0.1" >
    <sequence>     
        <module name="BoostMyShop_BarcodeInventory"/>     
    </sequence>
</module>
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It was my mistake. I put require js file outside of adminhtml folder in my custom module. That's why it is failed to override the 3rd party js file. Now it is working.